# LESS transition mixin

Tags: less, css-transitions, mixins

Can someone show how to use the following LESS mixin to transition the following property for **.25s** with **linear** ease?

**border-top: 6px solid #ff3300;**

```
.transition-properties(...) {
@props: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]/g, '')`;
-webkit-transition-property: @props;
-moz-transition-property: @props;
-o-transition-property: @props;
transition-property: @props;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Update: LESS 1.4+ Capability

With LESS 1.4, the javascript used in the original answer for the comma separated arguments is not needed. Instead, the use of a "dummy" semicolon at the end of the argument string causes the commas to be viewed as list separators, not argument separators, so this works now when imputing multiple transitions:

#### LESS 1.4+

The semicolon in the mixin call (`.transition-properties(border-top .25s linear, color .5s linear;);`)is very important. If it is ommited, the comma between the two parameters will be deleted which ends up in an invalid css rule.

```css
.transition-properties(...) {
  -webkit-transition: @arguments;
  -moz-transition: @arguments;
  -o-transition: @arguments;
  transition: @arguments;
}


.yourClass {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  .transition-properties(border-top .25s linear, color .5s linear;); /* semicolon is necessary */
}                                                                |
                                                          NOTE THIS SEMICOLON

.yourClass:hover {
  border-top: 6px solid #ff3300;
}
```

#### CSS Output

Note the comma stayed between the two property values:

```css
.yourClass {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: border-top 0.25s linear, color 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: border-top 0.25s linear, color 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: border-top 0.25s linear, color 0.5s linear;
  transition: border-top 0.25s linear, color 0.5s linear;
}
.yourClass:hover {
  border-top: 6px solid #ff3300;
}
```

### Original Answer [Pre LESS 1.4]

Obviously, specifics will depend on your exact implementation. However, this illustrates in general how you would use it:

#### LESS

```css
.transition-properties(...) {
@props: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]/g, '')`;
-webkit-transition: @props;
-moz-transition: @props;
-o-transition: @props;
transition: @props;
}


.yourClass {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  .transition-properties(border-top .25s linear);
}

.yourClass:hover {
  border-top: 6px solid #ff3300;
}
```

#### CSS Output

```css
.yourClass {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  -webkit-transition: border-top 0.25s linear;
  -moz-transition: border-top 0.25s linear;
  -o-transition: border-top 0.25s linear;
  transition: border-top 0.25s linear;
}
.yourClass:hover {
  border-top: 6px solid #ff3300;
}
```

**[See Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ6KT/4/)**

### Explanation

What the

```
@props: ~`"@{arguments}".replace(/[\[\]]/g, '')`;
```

allows you to do is put in multiple comma separated transitions, say:

```
.transition-properties(border-top .25s linear, color 1s linear);
```

Which will compile to keep them separated by a comma (just one line shown for example):

```
transition: border-top 0.25s linear, color 1s linear;
```

If you just used the straight `@arguments` you end up with ***no comma separation***:

```
transition: border-top 0.25s linear color 1s linear;
```

Which is not correct for the property.

Comment: It seems there is a mistake here: all transition-property should be replaced by transition since you are using the shortcut with multiple parameters (properties durations and easing type).

Comment: @arthur.sw: that is a good catch. I had merely followed the original code of the OP (which had `transition-property`) and made the LESS pass the values, not even noticing that it was the wrong "property" itself to call to set the timing and easing as well. I am going to fix that right now.